# Updating date in Datepicker (Angular) when date in first datepicker is set after second datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, watch

I am using two datepickers

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"
                     is-open="datepicker.dt" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate1" show-weeks="false" ng-required="true"
                     datepicker-options="dateOptions" show-button-bar="false"/>
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt2"
                     is-open="datepicker.dt2" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate2" show-weeks="false" ng-required="true"
                      show-button-bar="false" />
```

I set the minDate to today and the dt and dt2 to 2 weeks and 3 weeks from today respectively. Now I want the second datepicker to depend on the first datepicker and vice versa. If the date of the second datepicker is chosen some time before the first date the date of the first datepicker should instantly change its date to the same day as chosen for the second datepicker. Also, if the date of the first datepicker is chosen after the second date, the second datepicker should change automatically to same day as the chosen date of the first datepicker. I thought about using a `$watch` function. But that does not seem to work.

```
$scope.dt=Datepicker.daysToAdd();
```

and in my service:

```
DateSettings.daysToAdd=function(){
        newDate = newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+numberOfDaysToAdd);
        return newDate;
    };
```

Analogously for the second datepicker.

```
$scope.$watch('dt',function(){
          if($scope.dt.getTime()<=$scope.dt2.getTime()){
              Datepicker.daysToAdd();
          }else {
              $scope.dt2=$scope.dt;
          }
      });
```

How can I proceed from here as the $watch does not seem to do its job?!

Comment: I assume the default flow is such that when date is selected in first datepicker, second datepicker should not change. But when this flow is reversed, you want the datepickers to reflect your input. If you want same date in both datepickers, why don't you use a single scope variable as ng-model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.$watch('dt',function(oldVal,newVal,attr){          
      if($scope.dt > $scope.dt2){
          $scope.dt2 = newVal;
      }
});

$scope.$watch('dt2',function(oldVal,newVal,attr){
      if($scope.dt > $scope.dt2){
          $scope.dt = newVal;
      }    
});
```

Comment: First, thanks for your quick response. But could you provide some short explanation what exactly I should do? You are assigning a new value to dt2 and d1 but it should change if dt2 is set before dt (as an example) and d1 is set after dt2

Comment: Sorry, I dont see the answer yet ;)